# Flex + Drupal Sharing Data

Tags: php, apache-flex, drupal, flex3

I've looked around a bit and I can't seem to find the answer to this problem: in fact, this may be a stupid question and there isn't an answer.

So anyway; here's my problem.

I have a website that runs off of Drupal.  So, I've also started to mess around with Adobe Flex to create a few fancy drag/drop webapps that I'd like to embed into my Drupal site.  Now the question is this...

I want the application to know what you're logged in as.  So for example, I have an application that does college football voting and you only get one vote per week.  However, I want to avoid having the user have to type in their username and password...

Is there a way that I can get the application to get the current user_id out of the site, so I can put that behind the scenes and prevent users stuffing the ballot box or voting as someone else?

Any help would be great...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want to look at [Services](http://drupal.org/project/Services) module. In this module there is standard pre-configured services for getting user data and nodes data.

Drupal handbook also have some [examples](http://drupal.org/node/113697) for you.

Comment: Thanks, I think this may be pointing me towards what I need.  This will help me over the weekend

Comment: Thanks again for that link - it proved quite useful